# Difference in opencv and PIL affecting the model prediction

Tags: opencv, image-processing, keras, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network

I've trained a model in Keras for image classification. The training was performed by loading the images using pillow. During deployment the images are loaded in opencv which drops the accuracy of the model quite a bit. I've found that the image loaded by pillow and opencv are different when displayed.

```
im = Image.open("cat.jpg")
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
img = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To solve this issue i've tried to load the image in opencv and write it into a temp file and load it in pillow.

```
cv2.imwrite('cat2.jpg',img)
im1 = Image.open("cat2.jpg")
im == im1
```

*Output*

> False

I tried printing out the both `im1` and `im` as arrays and the values where completely different. I have to use opencv in deployment. Is there anyway in which i can retain the accuracy of the model ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with channel order difference in OpenCV and PIL. PIL loads image as `RGB` whereas OpenCV loads as `BGR`. Due to this, the blue and red channels seem swapped when you show the image with `matplotlib`.

You can convert the OpenCV image to `RGB` by using the `cv2.cvtColor` function as follows:

```
img = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```